# DJANGO: Error ninja.errors.ConfigError: Router@'/xxxxxxxx/' has already been attached to API NinjaAPI:1.0.0

Tags: python, django, docker, django-ninja

I am running a Django application in Docker when I spinup the docker container I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 94, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 128, in handle_uncaught_exception
    callback, param_dict = resolver.resolve_error_handler(500)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 597, in resolve_error_handler
    callback = getattr(self.urlconf_module, 'handler%s' % view_type, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 577, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/repo/repo/repo/urls.py", line 28, in <module>
    api.add_router("/xxxxx/", xxxxx_router)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ninja/main.py", line 367, in add_router
    self._routers.extend(router.build_routers(prefix))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ninja/router.py", line 366, in build_routers
    raise ConfigError(
ninja.errors.ConfigError: Router@'/xxxxx/' has already been attached to API NinjaAPI:1.0.0
```

The start script `start.sh` using gunicorn

```
 echo Starting Gunicorn.
export PYTHONPATH=repo
exec gunicorn repo.wsgi:application \
    --bind :8000 \
    --workers 5 \
    --threads 2 \
    --worker-class gevent \
    --timeout 120 \
    --limit-request-line 0 \
    --limit-request-fields 0 \
    --limit-request-field_size 0
```

Docker

```
RUN chmod -R 755 repo/start.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["repo/start.sh"]
```

Docker compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  repo:
    build: .
    platform: linux/amd64
    env_file:
      - .env.dev
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

I have looked checked if multiple instances of Ninja API
I have checked if I installed the api instance in multiple areas
https://github.com/vitalik/django-ninja/issues/229